# reference: mean value property for more general pdes

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Is there a more general set of equations that satisfy mean value properties, similar to the laplacian and heat equation? For example, finding some kernel K(x,y) and set $B(x,r)$ s.t.

$$u(x)=\int_{B(x,r)} u(y)K(x,y)dy.$$

Comment: Crossposted on MO: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/257879/reference-mean-value-property-for-more-general-pdes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar equations are studied in the field of [Fredhold equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fredholm_integral_equation) and [Volterra equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volterra_integral_equation), and more broadly speaking in the study of [integral equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_equation). They often, though not always, arise in the context of a variational formulation of a given PDE. The particular equation that you have written can be thought of (for suitable kernels $K$) as a fixed-point problem for a Fredholm integral operator.

Answer (score 0):

It generalizes for many elliptic and parabolic pdes:

1)"Spherical Means for Pdes"
edited by K. Karl Karlovich Sabelfeld, I. A. Shalimopva

2)"Spherical and plane integral operators for PDEs : construction, analysis, and applications", Karl K. Sabelfeld, Irina A. Shalimova,